# Value in moving from .NET to .COM

Tags: domains, godaddy

I have owned a website for about 6 years and it has been a .net site because some squatter has had the other. Recently the domain expired and once its freed up i plan on purchasing it. Is there any real value in me changing the entire site to .com or is it just as good to make the .com domain redirect to the .net website to save any trouble of breaking links and stuff?

Comment: Sorry but there is already many questions regarding TLD vs TLD as well as vs cTLD on Pro Webmasters.